# CSS grid formation of different height blocks

Tags: css

I need to implement a grid formation as follows:

```
+-------------------+ +--------+ +--------+
|1                  | |2       | |4       |
|                   | |        | |        |
|                   | |        | |        |
|                   | |        | |        |
|                   | +--------+ +--------+
|                   |
|                   | +--------+ +--------+
|                   | |3       | |5       |
|                   | |        | |        |
|                   | |        | |        |
|                   | |        | |        |
+-------------------+ +--------+ +--------+

+--------+ +--------+ +--------+ +--------+
|6       | |7       | |8       | |9       |
|        | |        | |        | |        |
|        | |        | |        | |        |
|        | |        | |        | |        |
+--------+ +--------+ +--------+ +--------+
```

Where the size of 1 is 2x the size of the other items (images) + margin. Also if the `viewport` is big enough, 6 and 7 should fall back next to 4 and 5. Ideally there would be a clean solution that would not involve having to wrap the elements into `containers` and/or no `JavaScript`, but I'm interested in hearing all the possible solutions.

P.S. `Flexbox` is out of question for my use case because of browser support, but I'm still interested in hearing possible solutions made with it.

P.P.S. 3 and 4 can swap places, but ideally they'd be in that order.

Comment: You forgot to add your code.

Answer (score 1):

You could just `float` the big grid element left and make all the other one's `inline-block`.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Jws3/)

#### HTML

```
<div class="big">1</div><div>2</div><div>3</div><div>4</div><div>5</div><div>6</div><div>7</div><div>8</div><div>9</div>
```

#### CSS

```
div {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}

.big {
    float: left;
    width: 210px;
    height: 210px;
}
```

Comment: This answer also doesn't maintain the wanted effect if the viewport size is increased, in essence this just puts everything on one row.

Comment: The size could be changed from `px` to `%` to allow the size to scale. I'm not too sure if there's a simple css solution to swap box 3 and 4 without using `flexbox` though.

Comment: I'm interested in hearing solutions that use flexbox too, although I won't be able to use them. :)

Answer (score 0):

Patsy: Heh, that's very stackoverflow of you. :D Anyway, here's what I have now:

```
<style>
.grid1, .grid2, .grid2-container {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

.grid1, .grid2 {
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.grid1 {
    width: 98px;
    height: 98px;
}

.grid2 {
    width: 218px;
    height: 218px;
}

.grid2-container {
    width: 250px;
    height: 230px;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}
</style>
<div class="grid2">1</div>
<div class="grid2-container">
    <div class="grid1">2</div>
    <div class="grid1">4</div>
    <div class="grid1">3</div>
    <div class="grid1">5</div>
</div>
<div class="clear">
    <div class="grid1">6</div>
    <div class="grid1">7</div>
    <div class="grid1">8</div>
    <div class="grid1">9</div>
</div>
```

As you can see, my current solution requires me to use containers and also to order my content in a non-linear pattern, so it's very far from optimal.

Answer (score 0):

Hey use media queries to get started

Cehck the following links

http://mediaqueri.es/

http://introducingthenovel.com/

http://mediaqueri.es/tuj/

Comment: I don't see how media queries would help here.